# How to toggle an individual pin out on an 8 bit shift register (Python - Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm fairly new to the Raspberry Pi and trying to wrap my head around the code I need to use the 8 bit shift register to control a set of relays I have managed to hook up.

The tutorial was one of the many 8-bit shift tutorials for blinking LED.

I can't wrap my head around how to alter the code to get the system to treat either a set of individual variables `(relay1, relay2, etc)` or `relay[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]` as a set of toggle type switches.

So that when a relay is triggered-only that relay is altered (on to off and vice versa) and the other ones don't cycle.

```python
while True:                       # execute loop forever
    for y in range(8):            # loop for counting up 8 times
        IO.output(data,1)         # pull up the data pin for every bit.
        time.sleep(clock_cycle)   # wait for 100ms
        IO.output(clock, 1)       # pull CLOCK pin high
        time.sleep(clock_cycle)
        IO.output(clock,0)        # pull CLOCK pin down, to send a rising edge
        IO.output(data,0)         # clear the DATA pin
        IO.output(shift,1)        # pull the SHIFT pin high to put the 8 bit data out parallel
        time.sleep(clock_cycle)
        IO.output(shift,0)        # pull down the SHIFT pin
```

Can someone show me what I'm pretty sure is a simple piece of code for setting individual outputs to on or off?

Comment: Looks like you are implementing so called **bit banging** protocol over GPIOs. Perhaps something with timing / flow is not correct? And general recommendation is forget about custom GPIO libraries and switch to `libgpiod`.

Comment: What shift register are you using?